# How to reference a document in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

My database has a table within it, let's call it 'doclist'. I want the table to display a document name, the date associated with it, and a link to download this file. After researching it seems that the file (looking to include a PDF or Word doc) needs to be stored somewhere within htdocs, and I will need to reference the file location within one of the table fields. What type of field would that need to be: varchar, blob, or text? The only other tutorials I have seen including files are just dumping data, where I want to reference a file and allow its download. Any direction would be very helpful at this point.

Comment: storing files in your db is generally almost always a mistake, and a major source of pain/problems. and use a type that's appropriate for your "document" type. if it's html, then it's just plaintext and a varchar would do. if it's binary garbage (e.g. zip, docx, etc...) then use a blob. don't use text/varchar for binary data - those fields are subject to charset translation rules and your binary data WILL get corrupted.

Comment: personally, I would go for two varchar fields. the first has a hash, corresponding to the filename stored on the server. the second field has the actual filename, so that when you deliver, you can rename the file to the original name.